# Isekai manga where the main character was reincarnated/transported to a fantasy world, as his parents were once before

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

The only thing I can remember is that, later in the manga, he was recognized by a person and transported into that person's own world (he created it) to train. He also find his parents' graves there, as it turns out that the person is one of their companions or something. Time flows faster in that world than the world he originally reincarnated into.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you recall anything distinctive about any of the characters (e.g. their appearance or dress) or the locations?

Comment: If anyone posts a correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons near the top-left corner of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.

Answer (score 2):

Is this ***[Chronicles of an Aristocrat Reborn in Another World](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/lg77t3s/tensei-kizoku-no-isekai-boukenroku-jichou-o-shiranai-kamigami-no-shito)***...?

> Teenager Shiinya Kazuya died while saving young girls from an attacker, only to find himself reincarnated into a world of swords and magic. It was a dream come true! Though he remembers his life and knowledge of Earth, he is now Cain von Silford, the third son of an aristocrat. Being granted the protection of the gods on his fifth birthday turned out to be too much of a good thing for Cain. His stats and boosts are so powerful, he must hide his real abilities to climb the ranks of society as he descends into the darkest dungeons. The ultimate isekai adventure begins as a teen-turned-child is trapped in a beautiful kingdom he didn’t create, but might one day rule.

As mentioned in the summary above, the protagonist was a Japanese teenager named Kazuya Shiina, who was killed defending some girls from a knife-wielding maniac and woke up as [Cain von Silford](https://chronicles-of-an-aristocrat.fandom.com/wiki/Cain_von_Silford), the third son of an aristocrat in a fantasy world.

In chapter 22, Cain walks through a doorway and is transported to another world from the fantasy world. Shortly thereafter, he encounters an unfamiliar man who alternately addresses him as both Cain von Silford and Kazuya Shiina.

The mystery man subsequently introduces himself as Yuuya Hirasawa, and explains that he himself was summoned to the fantasy world from Japan, though since he was summoned but not reincarnated, he retains his original Japanese body.

Yuuya has godlike powers now, and created this other world that he and Cain are presently in, which he's named Fabrinil. According to Yuuya, for each year that passes in Fabrinil, only a day passes in the fantasy world Cain was previously isekaied to.

[image: Chronicles of an Aristocrat Reborn in Another World, chapter 23, page 13.]

Yuuya also explains that he brought Cain to Fabrinil because he's been asked to train him to defeat an evil god called Arlong.

In chapter 25, Yuuya shows Cain the graves of his original Japanese parents, and reveals that they were summoned to the fantasy world at the same time as him.

[image: Chronicles of an Aristocrat Reborn in Another World, chapter 25, page 30.]